# Overuse route customizations - customize_count (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the `rails_best_practices` gem which tells me i have an error:

overuse route customizations (customize_count > 8)

```
  resources :stores do
    collection do
      get :api
    end
    member do
      get :printer
      get :delete
      get :inventory
      delete :inventory
      get :daysheet
      get :detailed_daysheet
      get :labels
      patch :restore
      patch :print_labels
      post :daysheet
    end
  end
```

Resulting in these paths:

```
api_stores_path GET /stores/api(.:format) stores#api
printer_store_path  GET /stores/:id/printer(.:format) stores#printer
delete_store_path GET /stores/:id/delete(.:format)  stores#delete
inventory_store_path  GET /stores/:id/inventory(.:format) stores#inventory
daysheet_store_path GET /stores/:id/daysheet(.:format)  stores#daysheet
detailed_daysheet_store_path  GET /stores/:id/detailed_daysheet(.:format) stores#detailed_daysheet
labels_store_path GET /stores/:id/labels(.:format)  stores#labels
DELETE  /stores/:id/inventory(.:format) stores#inventory
restore_store_path  PATCH /stores/:id/restore(.:format) stores#restore
print_labels_store_path PATCH /stores/:id/print_labels(.:format)  stores#print_labels
POST  /stores/:id/daysheet(.:format)  stores#daysheet
```

After refactoring, I need it to still function as it does now with `get` routes such as `/stores/7/inventory` and `/stores/18/printer`

How can i compress these get routes to accomplish the same routing goals?

Comment: Probably using nested resources. What have you tried?

Comment: @jvillian i tried `get ':store_action', constraints: { store_action: /printer|delete|inventory|daysheet|detailed_daysheet|labels/ }` inside the `member do`, but this led to an error.  How would i use nested resources here?  I've been searching online for a long time without success.

Comment: Did you read this one http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to do:

```
resources :stores do
  scope module: :stores do 
    resource  :printer,           only: [:show]
    resource  :daysheet,          only: [:show, :create]
    resource  :detailed_daysheet, only: [:show]
    resource  :inventory,         only: [:show, :destroy]
    resources :labels,            only: [:index]
    resources :print_labels,      only: [:update]
    resource  :restore,           only: [:update]
  end
  collection do
    get :api
  end
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end
```

Which gives you:

```
          store_printer GET    /stores/:store_id/printer(.:format)              stores/printers#show
         store_daysheet GET    /stores/:store_id/daysheet(.:format)             stores/daysheets#show
                        POST   /stores/:store_id/daysheet(.:format)             stores/daysheets#create
store_detailed_daysheet GET    /stores/:store_id/detailed_daysheet(.:format)    stores/detailed_daysheets#show
        store_inventory GET    /stores/:store_id/inventory(.:format)            stores/inventories#show
                        DELETE /stores/:store_id/inventory(.:format)            stores/inventories#destroy
           store_labels GET    /stores/:store_id/labels(.:format)               stores/labels#index
      store_print_label PATCH  /stores/:store_id/print_labels/:id(.:format)     stores/print_labels#update
                        PUT    /stores/:store_id/print_labels/:id(.:format)     stores/print_labels#update
          store_restore PATCH  /stores/:store_id/restore(.:format)              stores/restores#update
                        PUT    /stores/:store_id/restore(.:format)              stores/restores#update
             api_stores GET    /stores/api(.:format)                            stores#api
           delete_store GET    /stores/:id/delete(.:format)                     stores#delete
                 stores GET    /stores(.:format)                                stores#index
                        POST   /stores(.:format)                                stores#create
              new_store GET    /stores/new(.:format)                            stores#new
             edit_store GET    /stores/:id/edit(.:format)                       stores#edit
                  store GET    /stores/:id(.:format)                            stores#show
                        PATCH  /stores/:id(.:format)                            stores#update
                        PUT    /stores/:id(.:format)                            stores#update
                        DELETE /stores/:id(.:format)                            stores#destroy
```

Naturally, this requires that you create a number of new, nested controllers, such as `Stores::Printers` which will reside in `app/controllers/stores/printers_controller.rb`. But, you're now using standard RESTful routes, which I guess some people think is a good thing.

Also, for your nested routes, you'll have `:store_id` in the params instead of `id`.

That `collection api` and `member delete` still seem odd, but I'm not sure what the intention is there.

Comment: well, admittedly, I find this approach harder to read understand, but it does appear to do what i asked for.  I am just a bit hesitant to give it the checkmark because it entails creating several new resources and the routes aren't the same (which would mean i need to refactor and risk breaking multiple links in the site).  I really appreciate the work you put into this though, and if I don't see a better answer, I'll be happy to mark yours as being correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the path names aren't the same? If that's a problem, you can money with the `as:` argument. (I would updated code to demonstrate, but not much reason if this is heading in the wrong direction for you.) I think the only route that is different, possibly, is `print_labels`. Are there others?

Comment: While i normally really like the rails_best_practices gem, I think this is one case where it's pushing me toward a much more complicated solution than the working one I have already.  Thank you for all the work you put into answering this question, but in my case I'll stick with the solution i have.  Hopefully this thread will help others in the future.  Thanks!